# Functional programming problem over elements of a stream

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

I have to write a method which returns as result type `Optional<Integer>` and get as argument the elements: one `Stream<Integer> s`, one `Predicate<Integer> p` and `IntBinaryOperator b`.

Such that the method selects the elements for which `p` is `true` an if there is more than one returns the result of `b` between the elements of the `Stream` for which `p` is `true`

(ex. : a1 g a2 g a3 g a4 g a5 g) else return Optional .empty().

I've tried something like :

```
public Optional<Integer> concrete(Stream<Integer> s, Predicate<Integer> p, IntBinaryOperator b) {
    int counter = 0;
    Optional<Integer> val = Stream.of(p).findAny();
    if (val.isPresent() == true) {
        counter = counter + 1;
        if (counter > 1) {
            return val;
            return b;
        }
    } else {
        Optional<Integer> zer = Optional.empty();
        return zer;
    }
}
```

I don't know the way to find the true elements and return them with the binary operator between them.  **Any ideas please???**

Comment: Can you include the code you already have in your question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: *I have to write a method*, just try and remind yourself that ***I** have to write.*

Comment: i am sure that this is a bad effort but i have been stacked

int counter = 0;
 public Optional<Integer> concrete(Stream<Integer> s, Predicate<Integer> p, IntBinaryOperator b) {

  Optional<Integer> val = Stres.of(p).findAny(p);
  if (val.isPresent() == true) {
   counter = counter + 1;
            if (counter > 1) {
    return val;
    return b;
   }
  } else {
   Optional<Integer> zer = Optional.empty();
   return zer;
  }

 }

Comment: I would suggest editing the question with the code you've shared here and stating what exactly in it is not working for you?

Comment: Just to know everyone that i am a very beginner on java

Comment: What you are looking for are these operations on the Stream class: [Stream.filter()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) and [Stream.reduce()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-)

Comment: @RealSkeptic voting to reopen based on the inputs from OP. Have tried to update the question title to make much more sense. Feel free to edit further to improve.

Comment: @ThomasKläger what about `IntBinaryOperator`?

Comment: @PanagiotisExarchakos The `IntBinaryOperator` part is not still clear since that would work on two inputs. How do you process if the `p` is true for more than 2 inputs, do you keep on applying its functional implementation iteratively? I guess the implementation of `applyAsInt` would matter there.

Comment: @nullpointer I am not sure what is the issue you mentioned about the IntBinaryOperator.  I tried the stream filter but i think that didn't make correct syntax.

Comment: @nullpointer that just means that between `Stream.filter()` and `Stream.reduce()` there must be a call to `Stream.mapToInt(Integer::intValue)` (so the last call is actually not `Stream.reduce()`, but `IntStream.reduce()`

Comment: I needed to long to find out that my last comment was not comlete. The last remark should be: (so the last call is actually not `Stream.reduce()`, but `IntStream.reduce()`, which takes an `IntBinaryOperator` as argument).

Comment: @ThomasKläger True, that's what I was thinking of as well at that time.

Comment: maybe `public Optional<Integer> concrete(Stream<Integer> s, Predicate<Integer> p, IntBinaryOperator b) {
   List<Integer> intermediate = s.filter(p).collect(Collectors.toList());
        switch (intermediate.size()) {
            case 0:
                return Optional.empty();
            case 1:
                return Optional.of(intermediate.get(0));
            default:
                return Optional.of(intermediate.stream()
                        .mapToInt(i -> i)
                        .reduce(b)
                        .getAsInt());
        }
    }` @PanagiotisExarchakos

Comment: You should opt for `IntStream`, `IntPredicate`, `IntBinaryOperator` and `OptionalInt` as you are dealing with integers. `OptionalInt concrete(IntStream s, IntPredicate p, IntBinaryOperator b) { return s.filter(p).reduce(b); }`

Comment: @nullpointer I was thinking of `OptionalInt oi = s.filter(p).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).reduce(b);`. Since this returns an `OptionalInt` and since `OptionalInt` does not support `flatMap` this would need to be followed by a simple conditional statement: `return oi.isPresent() ? Optional.of(oi.getAsInt()) : Optional.empty();`